# Google Gears drag and drop upload

Tags: upload, file-upload, google-gears

I recently watched the google wave video from google i/o where they said you can drag and drop files from windows explorer to the browser and upload them using gears. Can someone point me in the right direction to do this myself? I've browsed around the gears api page on google code and can't really find any examples that even come close to this.

Answer (score 4):

You have some info here:
http://fvisticot.blogspot.com/2009/06/google-gears-desktop-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try plupload, it allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads. (See http://www.plupload.com/)

Answer (score 1):

i've also been looking - the best i've found so far is this but it's not very well documented

http://code.google.com/p/jquerymultiupload/

Josh

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good post about gears drag-drop upload with ASP.NET

http://coderbag.com/Web-Development/Drag-Drop-file-Upload-With-Google-Gears-and-ASP-NET

Answer (score -3):

I ended up finding a different solution.

I just used [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) (found it on Google). Not as slick as drag and drop, but it's a lot easier to set up and allows users to do multiple files at once.

Comment: Just used SWFUpload (google it)
Not as slick as drag and drop, but its a lot easier to set up and lets users do multiple files at once.